# Trying to import module of Npgsql.dll in the powershell script but fails including assembly into the script

Tags: powershell, odbc, npgsql, import-module

From my powershell script,i am trying to connect to Postgresql database.
    When i try to import Npgsql.dll, it throws "Cannot find type [System.Data.Npgsql.SqlCommand]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded"

```
    Import-Module '.\Npgsql.dll'
    #Add-Type -Path '.\Npgsql.dll'
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "Server=**;Port=**;User Id=**;Password=**;Database=**;"
    $cmdText = "select * from **"
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.Npgsql.SqlCommand($cmdText,$conn)
    $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the class you may be after is [NpgsqlCommand](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.html)

Try changing

```
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.Npgsql.SqlCommand($cmdText,$conn)
```

To

```
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.Npgsql.NpgsqlSqlCommand($cmdText,$conn)
```

Comment: It still throws the same error "Cannot find type [System.Data.Npgsql.NpgsqlSqlCommand]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded" and "Cannot find type [System.Data.Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded."

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine with Powershell 7.1.3 and Npgsql 5.0.4

```
try
{    
    Add-type -path "Npgsql.dll"
}
catch { $_.Exception.LoaderExceptions }

$connection = New-Object Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection("User ID=postgres;Password=***;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=test;")
try {
    $connection.Open()
    $cmd = New-Object Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand('INSERT INTO public."Demo" ("A", "B", "C") VALUES (@A, @B, @C)', $connection)
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("A", "Some")
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("B", 123)
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("C", "value")
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
} finally {
    $connection.Close()
}
```